# Installing a Text Editor to Edit appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Docker Container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

When it comes to configuration and Docker, I found that bashing into the container to make alterations was much easier than re-building and re-deploying Docker containers.

For example, an image that uses a Debian based image I am able to run `apt install nano` and alter configurations that way, then restart the container for the changes to take register.

My question is, how do I do this with a `dotnet` application with `appsettings.json` with a Dockerfile that Visual Studio has generated?  I see that its in the root directory when I bash into the container, but I can't use any commands like `apt install`.

Answer (score 2):

You should never directly edit files inside containers, if it's at all avoidable.  It's very routine to delete and recreate containers (to change a number of startup-time-only options; to update the image the container is running) and when you do this any changes you've made will get lost.

If you have a configuration file you'd like to appear in the container when you run it, you can use a Docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to have the copy of the file on the host replace the one in the container.  Start it with something like

```
docker run -v $PWD/appsettings.json:/appsettings.json ...
```

You can edit the file on your host with your favorite editor, without installing unnecessary tools in the container.  In principle this should be reflected immediately in the container, but you might need to restart your application/container to get it to notice.  Just so long as you specify this option when you delete and recreate the container, your change will be "persistent".

Comment: This is helpful. I arrived here from google, wanting to edit `appsettings` file.
If I am using docker-compose is there an equivalent for `-v`

Comment: Compose `volumes:` is the same.  There you can use relative paths `./appsettings.json:/appsettings.json` and they will be interpreted relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file.